# Laravel & Alpine.js | write dom element Alpine.js code based on PHP condition

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, alpine.js

This `updateSoftwareRequest` returns back with this data on error:

```php
    public function after(): array
    {
        return [
            function (Validator $validator) {
                if($validator->failed()) {
                    $validator->errors()->add('model', $this->route('software'));
                    session(['showUpdateSoftwareModal', true]);
                }
            }
        ];
    }
```

I want this `span` to get a `x-init` based on the `session` value. I am trying to achieve it like this:

```html
    <span x-data="{}" x-on:click="$dispatch('open-modal', 'edit-software-modal')" data-type="edit" {{ session('showUpdateSoftwareModal') === true ? 'x-init="console.log(\'HI\')"' : '' }}>Edit</span>
```

But when the value is `true` the `x-init` doesn't trigger write. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Just found this in the docs:

*You can add x-init to any elements inside or outside an x-data HTML block. For example:*

Does anyone know an alternate solution? I am trying to retrigger an edit-modal where fields inside that modal get populated from data attributes on the clicked buttons parent `td`. The error triggers from a form request and I am trying to trigger a specific rows' button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with quotes because they are escaped by the blade *{{ }}*, so instead of:

```php
{{ session('showUpdateSoftwareModal') === true ? 'x-init="console.log(\'HI\')"' : '' }}
```

you can use:

```php
{!! session('showUpdateSoftwareModal') === true ? 'x-init="console.log(\'HI\')"' : '' !!}
```

but I suggest you a different approach:

```php
<span x-data="{myFlag: {{ (int)session('showUpdateSoftwareModal', false) }} }"
      @click="$dispatch('open-modal', 'edit-software-modal')"
      data-type="edit"
      x-init="if (myFlag) {console.log('HI')}"
>
  Edit
</span>
```

that allows you to use *myFlag* everywhere you need in the Alpine object